# How to solve resolution setting in horizontal website

Tags: html, css, web

I am  designing horizontal website with 1024*768 resolution ,but when i changed the my computer resolution to 1600*900 that time website layout shows the some part of second page on a screen . what to do solve this ?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand why posters think we can help with things like this when they neither post any code nor link to a demonstration of the problem. Help us to help you!

Comment: Hi, nowhere near enough information to go on here I'm afraid. Please post up your code and/or a link to your website or a fiddle.

Comment: @Utkanos Because they think we are super hero's...

Comment: I don't actually think theres anything wrong with the question, I don't understand whats difficult to understand about it.

Comment: @John - so you'd say the question gives us enough info to answer it? It shows a code attempt or research effort?

Comment: @JonTaylor I didn't understood at all..what he means by second page here can you explain it to me bro.. -vzwick haha no I can't solve some of them without seeing the markup

Comment: Id say it gives enough to answer the question yes, I'm not saying it contains research effort but then this also isn't the sort of question where you need to give a coded answer.  Yes its always nice to see research effort/code etc but It isn't always necessary

Comment: @Mr.Alien He is doing something similar to jQueryUI where he has several pages (possibly of a slideshow) on one html page, he is then possibly transitioning between the pages.  The pages are fixed with the first resolution which means when he changes his screen resolution the fixed size pages are too small to fill the browser and thus he sees part of the second page in the browser window.

Comment: @JonTaylor most of the time I do like you, I answer, than the OP comes up with his different markup of what he has explained and want to achieve and than I get -1, -2

Comment: @Mr.Alien I agree sometimes it is annoying but more often than not we answer correctly.  If however we have gotten the wrong end of the stick theres nothing stopping us from deleting our answers.

Comment: @JonTaylor yea exactly, see a live example, no 1 care to reply us haha not even the OP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few main options.

- Completely disable the website using Javascript to detect screen resolution and redirecting if they have the incorrect resolution (*something I would not recommend*).
- Dynamically size everything so that everything scales based on the resolution.
- Pad out the extra space with a plain background colour and center the 1024 x 768 area. (*Note this will not work for people with smaller screen res than your fixed layout size*)

There are of course other options but I would consider these three.  It depends though what it is you are trying to achieve.